# How to insert an inline (heredoc maybe? ) python script into a bash stdin/stdout streaming pipeline

Tags: python, bash, redirect, heredoc

I have recently been doing fair amount of work in python and would like to be able to use its features instead of shell/bash builtins / shell scripting.

So for a shell  pipeline like this:

```
echo -e "Line One\nLine Two\nLine Three" | (cat<<-HERE | python
import sys
print 'stdout hi'
for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
  print ('stdout hi on line: %s\n' %line)
HERE
) | tee -a tee.out
```

All that is printed is  "stdout hi"

What needs to be fixed here?

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be better if you explained what your goal is with this construction. Maybe it could be simplified?

The problem is with this script that the `echo` goes to the `stdin` of the encapsulating shell initiated by the `(...)` notation. But inside the shell stdin is redefined as the [heredoc](/questions/tagged/heredoc) piped to [python](/questions/tagged/python), so it reads the script from stdin, which is now comes from the [heredoc](/questions/tagged/heredoc) pipe.

So you try something like this:

```
echo -e "Line One\nLine Two\nLine Three" |  python <(cat <<HERE
import sys
print "stdout hi"
for line in sys.stdin:
  print line.rstrip()
print "stdout hi"
HERE
)
```

Output:

```
stdout hi
Line One
Line Two
Line Three
stdout hi
```

Now the script is read from `/dev/fd/<filehandle>`, so `stdin` can be used by the `echo`'s pipe.

**SOLUTION #2**

There is another solution. The script can be sent to [python](/questions/tagged/python)'s stdin as here-is-the document, but then the input pipe has to be redirected to another file descriptor. For this an `fdopen(3)` like function has to be used in the script. I'm unfamiliar with [python](/questions/tagged/python), so I show a [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) example:

```
exec 10< <(echo -e "Line One\nLine Two\nLine Three")

perl <<'XXX'
print "stdout hi\n";
open($hin, "<&=", 10) or die;
while (<$hin>) { print $_; }
print "stdout hi\n";
XXX
```

Here the `echo` is redirected to the file handle 10, which is opened inside the script.

But the `echo` part can be removed (-1 `fork`), using an other [heredoc](/questions/tagged/heredoc):

```
exec 10<<XXX
Line One
Line Two
Line Three
XXX
```

**MULTILINE SCIPRT**

Or simply enter a multile script using the `-c` option:

```
echo -e "Line One\nLine Two\nLine Three"|python -c 'import sys
print "Stdout hi"
for line in sys.stdin:
  print line.rstrip()
print "Stdout hi"'
```

Comment: Maybe the construct you show python <(subshell) is what i were missing I am trying it out now

Comment: @javadba: But why not use `python -c '...'` instead of the `<(...)` version? It is more clean. Or if You need to create the script on the file, you could crate a temp file (`mktemp(1)`) and redirect the script there.

Comment: I nhave multiline script. How can that be done with python -c without the shell messing with the quotes?

Comment: @javadba: I added two more solutions. The last one is just using `-c`.