# Read stdin from inlined python in bash

Tags: python, bash

Can someone explain why this short bash / python command does not output "hello"

```
$ echo hello | python - <<END
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
  print line
END
```

If I save my python script to a file, this command works as expected.

In script.py

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
  print line
END
```

$ echo "hello" | python script.py

"hello"

Answer (score 7):

The reason it's not working is that you have conflicting redirections.  `echo | python` tries to tie standard input to the pipe from `echo`, while `python - <<HERE` tries to tie standard input to the here document.  You can't have both.  (The here document wins.)

However, there is really no reason to want to pipe the script itself on standard input.

```
bash$ echo hello | python -c '
> import sys
> for line in sys.stdin:
>   print line'
hello
```

Another solution might be to embed your data in a triple-quoted string within the script itself.

```
python <<\____
import sys
 
data = """
hello
so long
"""
 
for line in data.strip('\n').split('\n'):
   print line
____
```

The newlines between the triple quotes are all literal, but the `.strip('\n')` removes any from the beginning or the end. (You can't do that if you have significant newlines at the end, of course.)

The backslash before the here-document separator says to not perform any variable interpolation or command substitutions inside the here document. If you want to use those features, take it out (but then of course take care to individually escape any literal dollar signs or backticks in your Python code).

Answer (score 4):

Because `python << END` redirects stdin to read the *program*. You can't also read the line piped from `echo` on stdin.

Answer (score 4):

Oh boy, that makes sense! I've been struggling with this for the past hour and finally I understand, thanks both of you.

To provide a working alternative for the original program, you can do something like this:

```
$ echo hello | python <(cat <<END
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
  print line
END
)
```

But be careful! If you put this in a file, the final `END` need to be touching the left gutter (no whitespaces). Otherwise it won't parse with a 'unexpected end of file while looking for matching character' error or something like that (actually, this took me two more hours to figure out from when I started answering this).

Explaining the code, what is happening is that the `<<END ... END` combined with the `<(cat ...)` create a file (in `/dev/fd`) so that it can be fed to `python`, as if it were a real file. Quoting [this](https://superuser.com/a/404783/295116) explanation about `<(...)`:

> It's process substitution. It feeds the output of the command into a
>   FIFO that can be read from like a normal file.

There is another interesting answer about this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17098178/1814970).

Comment: That's an innovative but still fundamentally [useless use of `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html). The shell doesn't need the help of `cat` in a process substitution to feed the here document to Python, though the construct avoids tying up standard input (the shell basically makes the output from the process substitution available as a named temporary file).

Comment: @tripleee why useless? How else should I write above code, if a) I want to pass python code inline b) leverage quoting advantages with here documents c) still need arbitrary standard input to pass to python? Tried `<(< <<END ...)`, which does not work.

Comment: Click the link, it explains the problem exactly.

Comment: Yeah, read that link. But there is no mentioning of any here doc in the referenced section? I am afraid, it's still unclear to me.

Comment: @A_blop If you genuinely demand the script to be in a here document. this is hard to avoid, but still a bit of a wart. I updated my answer with another idea, but it won't work if you need the input to come from another process. (It could be adapted, but that would turn out kind of ugly, too.)

Comment: Putting the _other_ process in a process substitution might be more elegant, though: `python <<EOF <(echo "hello")` but then your Python code needs to be refactored to read a file argument instead of standard input.